# New line in HTML creates implicit margin

Tags: css

This must be a super common problem but I din't find a solution.

I get a margin between two `spans` that I do not want. Consider the following example.

style.css

```
.item {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

items.html

```
<div>
  <span *ngFor="let index of [1,2,3,4,5,6]" class="item">{{index}}</span>
  <span class="item">7</span>
</div>
```

1 to 6 stay together like best friends while 7 is treated like an outcast. Problem can be worked around by moving the `span` for 7 up to the same row as the others, but that won't fly with me.

Comment: It's because browser generates single space between your spans.

Comment: Probably you should post the code that is generated in AngularJS also tag this question for Angular JS, it seems to be more of an angular issue than css

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Justinas: I know that. I also know it is 'by design' for good reason. But in this particular case I want to 'disable' that behaviour.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I'll create a plunker or something. I just though that since most know the reason for the problem that some would have a solution without needing to run the code.

Comment: spans are inline elements - these are treat like words in a sentence, if there is space in between them, there will be a space added between them on the page - you either need to comment out the space, place them all on the same line next to each other or float the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered lots of times. It's because new line generates single white space between elements. To fix it:

```
<span></span><span></span>
```

---

```
<span></span><!--
--></span>
```

---

```
<div style="font-size: 0">
```

---

```
<span style="float: left">
```

Comment: if this is answered many times vote to close it as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I don't know could this help but I've just added
"float: left" into your "item" class. That works.

```
.item {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
 float: left;
}
```